# Changing the value of a mock input object after it's initialized in beforeEach()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm working on testing a component, *child.component.ts*. The component has a simple conditional that outputs a status based on the values of an object. The object is passed in via an `Input()` to the component from a parent component. I've created a mock object in the `beforeEach()` of the test and I'm trying to alter this object in the second `it()` statement so that the two properties have different values.

This is a simplified application to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. The fundamental logic in the actual one is exactly that of the one I'm providing code for below, however the object that I have to mock in the actual unit test is *exponentially* larger and is an interface type so all properties must be present--hence the desire for keeping it within the `beforeEach()`. Parts of this logic are shared between a few different tests, so if it's possible to just change the object value in the one place where I'm trying to do so, that would be ideal... otherwise it'd add another 40+ lines to my code.

Child.component.spec.ts:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // Set up the fake dataItem objet
    component.dataItem = {
      documentCount: 3,
      invoiceCount: 4
    };

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Works as expected
  it('should have a status of 1 if there are documents or invoices', () => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.status).toBe(1);
  });

  // Setting the documentCount and invoiceCount here doesn't seem to work
  it('should have a status of 0 if there are no documents or invoices', () => {
    component.dataItem.documentCount = 0;
    component.dataItem.invoiceCount = 0;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.status).toBe(0);
  });
```

App.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  dataItem = {
    documentCount: 3,
    invoiceCount: 4
  };
}
```

App.component.html:

```
<app-child [dataItem]="dataItem"></app-child>
```

Child.component.ts:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dataItem;

  status: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.dataItem.documentCount === 0 && this.dataItem.invoiceCount === 0) {
      this.status = 0;
    } else {
      this.status = 1;
    }
  }

}
```

Child.component.html:

```
<p>{{ this.status }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `component.dataItem.documentCount = 0;` and `component.dataItem.invoiceCount = 0;` don't work could be because this object is a reference type and changing a property on a reference type doesn't make change detection take place OR most likely because `ngOnInit` is not ran again.

Structure your tests like so:

```
let stockDataItem = {
      documentCount: 3,
      invoiceCount: 4
};

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  describe('stock dataItem', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
       // set dataItem
       component.dataItem = stockDataItem;
       // this fixture.detectChanges() will call ngOnInit. 
       // the first fixture.detectChanges() calls ngOnInit after createComponent
       fixture.detectChanges();
     });
    // Works as expected
    it('should have a status of 1 if there are documents or invoices', () => {
      expect(component.status).toBe(1);
    });
  });

  describe('0 invoice count and 0 document count', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
       // set dataItem
       component.dataItem = {...stockDataItem, invoiceCount: 0, documentCount: 0};
       fixture.detectChanges();
     });

   // Setting the documentCount and invoiceCount here doesn't seem to work
   it('should have a status of 0 if there are no documents or invoices', () => {
     expect(component.status).toBe(0);
   });
  });
```